# Task created upon Opportunity creation - Where is this code likely located?

Tags: trigger, tasks

Right now my SF is set up so that when someone creates an Opportunity over a certain amount ($1000), a Task is created and assigned to a user. I'd like to edit it so that it only creates the task if a specific condition is not met. Where could I do so? Thank you.

Comment: You need look at trigger, workflow rules, process builders to see where is this getting created and modify accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't seem to be in the Trigger section for Opportunities (which is where I would have thought it would be) so I will look at Workflow Rules and Process Builders.

Comment: @JayantDas it was in workflow rules. If you'd like to post that as an answer I will accept it. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there are certain operations say creating related records or updating related record upon creation of a parent record, and that you need to find out where it could possibly happen, you will need to verify it in either of these locations for that Object:

- Trigger
- Workflow Rules
- Process Builder
- Scheduled/Batch Processes